# Plot the x as y and vice versa

Tags: plotting

How can I plot the x as y and vice versa? I am trying to get the following (without rasterizing or reflecting the text):

[image]

```
ImageReflect[#, Left] &@ Rasterize@Rotate[#, 90 Degree] &@
ComplexPlot[Zeta[z], {z, -.5, 1.5 + 60 I}, ImageSize -> 100, AspectRatio -> 10]
```

Motivation is to use `Show` to display, eg. `RiemannSiegelZ` plot over the above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ComplexPlot[
 Zeta[I Conjugate[z]], {z, I Conjugate[-.5], I Conjugate[1.5 + 60 I]},
  ImageSize -> 600, AspectRatio -> 1/10]
```

[image]

```
ComplexPlot[
  Zeta[I Conjugate[z]], {z, I Conjugate[-4], I Conjugate[3.1 + 60 I]},
   ImageSize -> 800, AspectRatio -> 0.3, Frame -> False, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Axes -> True];
Plot[RiemannSiegelZ[x], {x, 0, 60}];
Show[%%, %]
```

[image]